# A better phrase for saying "Do you Find" I want to say (do you find yourself always seeking the house for Gloves while running to the school bus)

Tags: word-choice

I want to say (do you find yourself always seeking the house for Gloves while running to the school bus)A better phrase for saying "Do you Find"

Comment: It's not ***seek*** - you ***search*** some location [for something]. The idiomatic usage *Do you **find yourself** [doing something]?* has no semantic connection to the normal sense of ***finding*** as the result of a successful search.

Answer (score 1):

Although "do you find" is idiomatic, it is also perfectly OK to use. Some other options could include the following:

- Are you in the habit of searching for your gloves just before running to catch your bus?
- Have you ever found yourself searching for your gloves just before running to catch your bus?
- Has this ever happened to you: Just before running to catch your bus you search the house frantically for your gloves?
- Do you have a tendency to search your house frantically for your gloves just before running to catch your bus?

There are probably many other ways of saying the same thing (or nearly so), but your initial way of using "do you find" is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes +1. The only major problem with the OP's sentence was the use of the word "while". Had that been replaced with "before" the sentence would have been comprehensible, albeit that a few other changes would have improved the cosmetics.